# Play framework SIGTERM lifecycle

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to have my application do a grace full shutdown, for that to happen i need to

1. Stop receiving new connections
2. Turn off thread pools (gracefully wait for them to finish)
3. Turn off application

I know you can send a SIGTERM to play, but I not sure what play is doing when he gets that signal.

Answer (score 0):

You should inject `ApplicationLifecycle` into your class \ module, and add a stop hook.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import javax.inject._
import play.api.inject.ApplicationLifecycle

@Singleton 
class MessageQueueConnection @Inject() (lifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle) {
   val connection = connectToMessageQueue()
   lifecycle.addStopHook { () =>
      Future.successful(connection.stop())
   }

   //...
}
```

You can read some more [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Stopping/cleaning-up)